# How to convert a Mathematica code into Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

This is the Mathematica code:

First, execute sfDivide and sfCollatz.

```
sfDivide[n_, d_] := n/Times @@ Select[d, Divisible[n, #] &]
sfCollatz[n_, m_, d_, max_ : 2^64, iterations_ : 1000] := 
 NestWhileList[
  If[
    Or @@ Divisible[#, d],
    sfDivide[#, d],
    m # + 1] &, n, UnsameQ[##] && Last[{##}] < max &, All, iterations]
```

This pr Mathematica code is what I want to convert into Python.

```
pr = ParallelTable[{n, m, d, sfcollatz[n, m, d]}, {n, 1, 100}, {m, 3, 10}, {d, 2, 3, 5, 7}];
```

You can see the function sfCollatz in Python that I have converted. I only want to convert the variable pr program. Please help!!!

```
def sfcollatz(n,divs,mult,inc,maxSize):
result = []
while n not in result and len(result)!=maxSize:
    result.append(n)
    d = next((d for d in divs if n%d==0),None)
    n =  (n*mult+inc) if not d else n//d
    s = mult*result[-1]+inc
    
return result + [...]*(n not in result) + [s]
```

I am trying to rewrite the pr Mathematica code into Python, but I just don't know how to convert this into python.

Okay I figured out the list of lists part. But how can have sfcollatz like : ParallelTable[{n, m, d, sfcollatz[n, m, d]}, {n, 1, 100}, {m, 3, 10}, {d, 2, 3, 5, 7}];

```
listoflists = []
for n in range(1,101):
    sublist = []
    for m in range(3,11):
      sublist = []
      for d in (2,3,5,7):
        sublist.append((n,m,d))
    listoflists.append(sublist)
print (listoflists)
```

This is my new edited code, but it gives an error:

```
result = []
for n in range(1,101):

   for mult in ([3]):
      
     for divs in ([2],[3],[5],[7]):

         while n not in result and len(result)!=2000000000:
             result.append(n)
             d = next((d for d in divs if n%d==0),None)
             n =  (n*mult+1) if not d else n//d
             s = mult*result[-1]+1
   data = result + [...]*(n not in result) + [s]


 print(data)
```

Comment: which bit are you struggling on or what is the error please ?   i notice that some basics like indentation are missing from the code snippet sent (python needs indentation).

Comment: I'm confused that Python doesn't have a Parallel Table command and I don't know how to make the [{n, m, d, sfcollatz[n, m, d]}, {n, 1, 100}, {m, 3, 10}, {d, 2, 3, 5, 7}] in python because I did some research about mathematica and the code above is called a table function, but in python I don't think they have one.

Comment: what you refer to as a `parallel table` appears to be the equivalent of a list of lists or a dict in python (according to mathematica). I am looking here to get this info:   https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html   (i have not used mathematica for years, so if you have an example, then it might be possible to help).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help! I created a list of lists in python, but how can I have sfcollatz into this? Like the pr.

Comment: i dont know what `sfcollatz` is exactly, but parsing values into a list of lists is as simple as indexing `list_name[i][j]`. So just need to make sure that you get the indexing (i and j) the correct way around. The first index is the first list and the second index is for the second list.

Comment: you might be interested in sympy (python library for symbolic mathematics). Here is a function for parsing Mathematica code: <https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.mathematica.mathematica>. While I can definitely recommend sympy, I have no experience with parsing Mathematica code. You should consider adding the sympy tag, to attract people who might have such experiences.